Power bank 4s voltage monitoring using cd4052
i working on pcb with a 18 volt dc like circuit below . I have a question about driving logic A and B of cd4052 with my esp32 do my circuit is correct. Do I need extra component between Drain of the irf5305 and Ground.

Which CD4052 is that? Not all tolerate that high supply voltage.  Some are limited to 15V.

@Khales, if you wish to show a redrawn version of the circuit add it as an edit section at the end of your question and attribute it to me please. No need to amend my answer because if it had been approved I may not have been able to check it. When you have amended your question (as mentioned), please repy to this comment so I can check it. If we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Andy Can you correct the edit circuit ?

@KhalesNaim no need to correct it; it's already correct and as clear as day. If we are done here, please take note of this: What should I do when someone answers my question. If you are still confused about something then leave a comment to request further clarification.

Carried out a rollback because the answer became obsolete as a result.


Do I need extra component between Drain of the irf5305 and Ground

There are several problems with your design: -

Possibly you intended to use a P channel MOSFET in which case you need to swap drain and source.

Thanks again for your usefull comment If i use n channel mosfet normaly the load " A" must be connected to Drain of the N channel mosfet right ?
Or

It can be used as a source follower to avoid signal being inverted
